# Showing $\sum 1/a_i<2$: is my proof correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I am attempting a problem I found in a book, the book contains mostly fairly tricky problems so I am not sure whether what I've done works or not. If not, I would appreciate a hint instead of a solution (the book has solutions at the end, which I'd rather not check for now).

**Problem** Let $A=\{a_0, \dots \, a_n\}\subseteq\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ such that $\sum_{i\in S} a_i$ is distinct for all $S\subseteq \{0,\dots, n\}$. Show that $\sum_A 1/a_i<2$.

**Some ideas**: The natural approach is to bound by $\sum_0^n 2^{-i}$. WLOG $a_{i+1}>a_i$. Note that by the pigeonhole principle, $\sum_0^{j} a_i\geqslant 2^{j+1}-1$ for all $0\leqslant j\leqslant n$. To this effect, write $a_i=2^{i}+\epsilon_i c_i$ where $c_i\geqslant 0$ and $\epsilon_i=\pm 1$ (in other words, the 'deviation' from the powers of $2$). In particular, $\epsilon_i c_i<0$ implies $\epsilon_j c_j>0$ for some $j<i$.

Let $q= \min\{i\geqslant 0:\;\epsilon_i c_i>0 \}$. Now **if** $\epsilon_{i+1} c_{i+1}<0$ then I *think* we are in luck, because we can define $p+1=\min\{i>q:\; \epsilon_i c_i\geqslant 0\}$, so that:
$$c_q\geqslant c_{q+1}\dots+ c_p$$
we can then compare the $\sum_q^p 1/a_i$ to $\sum_q^p 2^{-i}:$

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_q^p \left(\frac{1}{2^{i}}-\frac{1}{a_i}\right)  &=\sum_q^p \left(\frac{1}{2^{i}}-\frac{1}{2^{i}+\epsilon_i c_i}\right) \\ &=\left(\frac{1}{2^{q}}-\frac{1}{2^{q}+c_q}\right)+\sum_{q+1}^p\left(\frac{1}{2^i}-\frac{1}{2^i-c_i}\right)\\&\geqslant \left(\frac{1}{2^q}-\frac{1}{2^q+\sum_{q+1}^p c_i}\right)+\sum_{q+1}^p\left(\frac{1}{2^i}-\frac{1}{2^i-c_i}\right) \\ & =  \frac{\sum_{q+1}^p c_i}{2^q(2^q+\sum_{q+1}^p c_i)}-\sum_{q+1}^p\frac{c_i}{2^i(2^i -c_i)}\\ &=\frac{1}{2^q}\sum_{q+1}^p c_i\left(\frac{1}{2^q+\sum_{q+1}^p c_i}-\frac{1}{2^{i-q}(2^i- c_i)}\right)\\ &>0\end{aligned}$$
because $2^q+\sum_{q+1}^p c_i\leqslant 2^q+c_q<2^i-c_i=2^{i-q}(2^i-c_i)$ for $q<i$ (in other words $a_q<a_i$). In theory I think if the issues below can be fixed, then each 'block' of '$\epsilon_i c_i>0$ then $\epsilon_ic_i \leqslant 0$' could be treated the same.

**Issues**:

- the first glaring one is that is all relies on $\epsilon_{i+1}c_{i+1}<0$, whereas in theory we could have many terms increase faster than powers of $2$ before (possibly) slowing down, and then it seems harder to compare a series of $2^i+c_i$ to a series of $2^j-c_j$.
- I think the 'leftover' from $c_q-\sum_{q+1}^p c_i$ would also need to be taken into account for terms $i>p$ etc. This also applies to the case $p=q$.

As mentioned, I would really appreciate a hint over a solution. Many thanks for reading.

[**Edit**: replaced $[n]$ with $\{0,\dots,n\}$ for clarity]

Comment: The notation in "$\sum_{i\in S} a_i$ is distinct for all $S\subseteq A$" is very confused. You meant "$\sum_{a\in S} a$ is distinct for all $S\subseteq A$".

Comment: For example, if $S=A=\{1,3\}$ then $\sum_{i\in S} a_i = a_{1}+a_3$, which makes no sense, because there's no such thing as $a_3$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes sorry, I mean $S\subseteq [n]=\{0,\dots, n\}$. Fixed now!

Comment: That's probably a better notation than what I said. But you really need to define $[n]$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $[n]$ has become a fairly common notation in recent years. I have seen it in multiple texts defined exactly as moonerism defined it in the comment. True, it is better to define it, but it is becoming a standard notation.

Comment: You could have just added the definition to the question in less time than it took to write that comment. Common or not, it's not standard, so it needs to be defined.

Comment: This looks too complicated.  I would try to prove by induction that the biggest value with $n$ terms is $2-2^{1-n}$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The book uses that notation without comment, so I assumed it was standard enough, but I'll change it so that it is clear to everyone.

Comment: @saulspatz This was my first approach actually, but I wasn't able to do it successfully because the 'last term' can be larger than the corresponding $½$-power, compensating for the previous terms being small enough, so the proof comes back round to looking at the effect these deviations, which is what I tried above. If you have an idea on how to get around that though I'd love to hear!

Comment: I don't follow.  Suppose the sum of $n$ reciprocals is $\geq 2$.  By the induction hypothesis, the $n$th term is less than $2^{n-1}$.  Since the terms are in increasing order, we have $n$ terms, all less than $2^{n-1}$ and distinct subset sums.  Surely this can't happen.

Comment: @saulpatz Apologies if I misunderstand, so assume $\sum_0^k 1/a_i<2-2^{-k}$ for $k<n$ (is this the hypothesis you have in mind?). How would you get $\sum_0^n 1/a_i< 2-2^{-n}$ without knowing $1/a_i<2^{-n}$ (which we can't know)?

Comment: Just a comment: the notation $\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ is redundant, as all natural numbers are greater than zero.

Comment: @K.defaoite In my country $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$, and $\mathbb{N}^*$ or $\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ or even $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ are used to denote the positive integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your proof, but I suggest a different aproach (using your idea to compare with the sum of the inverses of the powers of $2$): try to proof a **stronger** result, that is $$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{a_i} \le \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{2^i} = 2-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$
under the same hypothesis.

Assume as you did that $a_0<a_1<a_2<\cdots <a_n$.

As you said, one can easily show that 
$$S_j:=\sum_{i=0}^j a_i \ge \sum_{i=0}^j 2^i=2^{j+1}-1=: D_j$$
for all $0\le j\le n$.

Moreover, one has $a_i2^i<a_{i+1}2^{i+1}$ obviously.

Now, we will compute 
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{2^i}-\frac{1}{a_i}\right)= \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{2^ia_i}\left(a_i-2^i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{2^ia_i}\left((S_i-S_{i-1})-(D_i-D_{i-1})\right)=$$
$$= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{2^ia^i}-\frac{1}{2^{i+1}a_{i+1}}\right)\left(S_i-D_i\right)+\frac{1}{2^na_n}\left(S_n-D_n\right) \ge 0$$
as $S_i-D_i\ge 0$ for all $i\ge 0$ as it is $$\left(\frac{1}{2^ia^i}-\frac{1}{2^{i+1}a_{i+1}}\right)> 0$$

Comment: Hello, I don't quite see how this works, but please correct me if I am missing something. If we assume $\sum_0^n 1/a^i\leqslant 2-2^{-n-1}$ then to get $\sum_0^{n+1} 1/a_i< 2-2^{-n-2}$ we would need to use $a_{n+1}>2^{n+2}$, but this is not necessarily the case? Similarly if we try using a stronger bound like $\leqslant 2-2^{-n}$ we'd need $a_{n+1}>2^{n+1}$ but again, this is necessarily true.

Comment: Hi. In fact you need to show that if $\{a_0,\dots,a_n\}\subset \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that all the sums $\sum_{i\in I} a_i$ are distinct for all $I\subset \{0,\dots,n\}$ and $a_i<a_j$ for all $i<j$, then $a_n\ge 2^n$.

Comment: Yes but what I meant was this is not true, which is what makes this tricky. If we 'push upwards' sufficiently many terms (the $+c_i$ I refer to), then it's possible for a later term to have a $-c_i$ i.e. be $<2^i$ and the condition to still hold. For instance $\{ a_i \} = \{11,17,20,22,23,24\}$ where $a_5<2^5$ we have $2^5$ distinct sums (including the empty sum).

Comment: Found some simpler examples: $\{3,5,6,7\}$ and $\{6,9,11,12,13\}$

Comment: @moonerism You are right. I still believe the assertion I said is true, but the naive approach to do induction does not work as you said.

Comment: @Nulhomogous I agree, it certainly seems that way. But this little issue is why I gave up on induction and tried something a little uglier instead, which by the looks of it is still far from ideal...

Comment: Hi, yes this is essentially a proof of Karamata's inequality with a specific choice of sequence. The sum manipulations are quite clever and hard to come up with (in my opinion anyway).

Comment: Sure, also I wrote out the book's solution which uses similar ideas but differently, if you are interested in reading.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I will type out (hopefully correctly) the answer given in the book which differs from the other one posted, in case anyone would like to see more than one method!

---

Have $a_{i}<a_{i+1}$. The proof is carried out by induction on the stronger statement that if $\sum_0^k a_i\geqslant \sum_0^k b_i$ for all $k\in [n]$ where $\{b_i\}_0^n$ satisfies $0 <b_i<b_{i+1}$ then $\sum_0^n a_i^{-1}\leqslant \sum_0^n b_i^{-1}$.

The base case is trivial, suppose the assertion holds $\forall k< n$ and take $\{a_i\}^n_0$ with the distinct sum property. Then $\sum_0^k a_i\geqslant 2^{k+1}-1$ by the pigeonhole principle (this is in fact the only use of that property).

- If $\sum_0^k a_i=2^{k+1}-1$ for some $0\leqslant k<n$ then we are done since the sequence can be broken up into two of length $<n$ satisfying the condition. More precisely we would get:
  $$\sum_{0}^k a_i= \sum_0^k 2^i\qquad \text{and}\qquad\sum_{0}^{n-k-1} a_{i+k+1}\geqslant \sum_0^{n-k-1} 2^{i+k+1}$$
  which recombine to $\sum_0^n a_i^{-1}\leqslant \sum_0^n 2^{-i}$ after the hypothesis is applied.
- Otherwise $\sum_0^k a_i>2^{k+1}-1$ for all $k<n$. The clever part is now to define the smallest deviation between both *sums*:
  $$\lambda=\min\left\{\sum_0^k a_i-2^i\;\big|\;k<n\right\}$$
  One can then define a new sequence $\{a'_i\}_0^n$ where $a_i'=a_i$ for $0<i<n$, $a_0'=a_0-\lambda$ and $a_n'=a_n+\lambda$
  Then $\sum_0^k a_i'\geqslant \sum_0^k 2^i$ with equality for some $k$, so by hypothesis $\sum_0^n (a_i')^{-1}\leqslant \sum_0^n 2^{-i}$. Furthermore (by convexity of $x\mapsto x^{-1}$) we have $(a_0-\lambda)^{-1}+(a_n+\lambda)^{-1}>a_0^{-1}+a_n^{-1}$ so $\sum_0^n a_i^{-1}< \sum_0^n 2^{-i}$.